# imageview always center in tableview

Tags: ios, imageview, tableview, appcelerator

i have a appcelerator project, in IOS and Android.

The problem is when i need a tableview with a imageview inside the rows.
In Android i can put the image1 near the left border, but in iOS imageview always is centered. 
Where is the problem????

Thanks

My Code:

```
for (i=0;i<NRegistros;i++){

    TablaSerieTermostatos[i]=rows.field(0);
    leoSerie=rows.field(0);
    TablaPinTermostatos[i]=rows.field(1);
    leoPin=rows.field(1);
    TablaNombreTermostatos[i]= rows.field(2);
    TablaTemperTermostatos[i]= rows.field(345);

    var nuevaRow=Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height:200, backgroundSelectedColor: "white"});  

    var cuadroexterno=Ti.UI.createView({
        id: "CuadroExterno",
        backgroundColor: "white" ,
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        left:"0%",
        top:"5%"
    });
    var titulo1=Ti.UI.createLabel({
        id: "NombreTerm",
        text: TablaNombreTermostatos[i],
        font: {fontSize: '27'},
        color: "#0060a7" ,
        textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT, 
        left: "50%",
        top:"35%"
    });
    var imagen1=Ti.UI.createImageView({
        id: "Radiador",         
        image: "/Copiar Emisor.png",
        height: "70%",
        //left:"15%",
        top:"10%"
    });                 


    if (Ti.Platform.name=="iPhone OS") {
        imagen1.right = "40%";
        titulo1.left = "55%";
    }       
    else imagen1.left="15%";

    cuadroexterno.add(imagen1);
    cuadroexterno.add(titulo1);
    nuevaRow.add(cuadroexterno);        

    $.TablaCopiar.appendRow(nuevaRow);
    rows.next();
}
```

Alloy:

```
    <TableView id="TablaCopiar" top="20%" height="80%" left="0%" zindex="20" width="100%" backgroundColor="white" visible="false" separatorColor="gray" >
    </TableView>
```

[The screen in IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYeoQ.png)

[The screen in Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yezrm.png)

Comment: Can you provide a simple design outline of how you want your tableview rows? Because problem cannot be find out from this code as there can be some UI calculations somewhere else in your app. We can then suggest you better code using Alloy as well.

Comment: Thanks Prashant, now you can see more information in the code and screens in IOS and Android. I use Alloy in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code after creating a new controller with name as **TableRow**:

```
var table_rows = [];

for (i=0;i<NRegistros;i++){
    TablaSerieTermostatos[i]=rows.field(0);
    leoSerie=rows.field(0);
    TablaPinTermostatos[i]=rows.field(1);
    leoPin=rows.field(1);
    TablaNombreTermostatos[i]= rows.field(2);
    TablaTemperTermostatos[i]= rows.field(345);

    table_rows.push(Alloy.createController('TableRow', {
        text : TablaNombreTermostatos[i]
    }).getView());  

    rows.next();
}       

$.TablaCopiar.data = table_rows;
```

***TableRow.xml***

```
<Alloy>
    <TableViewRow height="200" backgroundSelectedColor="white">
        <View class="views">
            <Label id="NombreTerm" class="row-labels" />
            <ImageView id="Radiador" class="left-images"/>
        </View>
    </TableViewRow>
</Alloy>
```

***TableRow.tss***

```
".views" : {
    width : Titanium.UI.FILL,
    height : Titanium.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor : "white"
}

".left-images" : {
    left : 70,
    height : '70%',
    image : "/Copiar Emisor.png"
}

".row-labels" : {
    textAlign : Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
    color : "#0060a7",
    font: {fontSize: '27'}
}
```

***TableRow.js***

```
$.NombreTerm.text = $.args.text;
```

Comment: Thanks Prashant. I have resolved by modifying the code.